# Django and extending templates not working?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am using Django to build my blog site and i am unable to extand a template in my project.

I have two templates:

1. base.html
2. post.html

Base.html is my parent template and post.html is my child template extending base.html.

I am unable to get Django to extend post.html. When i run the web server base.html displays but there is not text from post.html on it.

I have read the Django documentation on templates and how to extend, i believe i have to syntax correct, but i am not sure why its not working?

I am also using Boostrap with this project.

Thank you for your help,
Nermin

post.html

```
  {% extends "post/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="blog-post">
            <h2 class="blog-post-title">Sample blog post</h2>
            <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>

            <p>Blog text goes here.</p>


    </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
{% endblock  %}
```

enter code here

base.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <!-- load static files -->
    {% load staticfiles %}

    <title>Blog Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'  %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/blog.css'  %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
          <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">About</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- blog post goes here -->

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}


    <div class="container">

      <div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title">Code'N Cofee Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description">Live and write code. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">


          <nav>
            <ul class="pager">
              <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

        </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
            <h4>About</h4>
            <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-module">
            <h4>Archives</h4>
            <ol class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-module">
            <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
            <ol class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <footer class="blog-footer">
      <p>Blog template built for <a href="http://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
      </p>
    </footer>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nermic Kekic's answer didn't work for me.

I am not a expert but below is what worked for me.

The problem was my base.html(parent) didn't know where to append the post.html(child) so I had to mention

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

these two lines in body of my base.html also then it worked for me, as this block will tell the post.hml where to show the content of child.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The issue was not with the two html files, but it was in my views.py file. Basically in my index function in views.py was rendering base.html and therefore nothing was showing up on screen from post.html

Given that the post.html is extending base.html i needed to edit my index function to return and render post.html like bellow and this fix the code.

Hope this helps anyone else that is having similar issue.

This is the way my index function looks now in views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'post/post.html', {'': ''})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

You need to add above lines of code in your `base.html` file. And in your (post.html) file, you need to add these lines and the unique content inside these. This way Django knows where you can make changes to your post.html file.